# powershell: how to run multiple dacservice.deploy calls in a sequence

Tags: powershell, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have to run `dacservice.deploy` to update database from version `$from` to version `$to`. Here is my ps script:

```
#deploy
For ($i=$from; $i -le $to; $i++) {    
    $dacpacFileName = $dacpacPathName + $i + '.dacpac'

    Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Output "Deploying... $dacpacFileName to $databaseServerName\$targetDatabaseName"
    Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"

    #dacpac    
    $dp = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load($dacpacFileName)    

    #options
    $options = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacDeployOptions
    $options.GenerateSmartDefaults="True"
    $options.BlockOnPossibleDataLoss="False"
    $options.IncludeTransactionalScripts = "True"

    #deploy
    $dacService.Deploy($dp, $targetDatabaseName, $upgradeExisting, $options)     
}
```

Currently `dacService.Deploy` are running in parallel for some reasons.

[image]

Anyway to ask it to run one-by-one?

PS: I can do with `sqlPackage.exe`:

```
#deploy
For ($i=$from; $i -le $to; $i++) {    
    $dacpacFileName = $dacpacPathName + $i + '.dacpac'

    Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Output "Deploying... $dacpacFileName to $databaseServerName\$targetDatabaseName"
    Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"

    & $sqlPackageExePath /a:Publish /sf:$dacpacFileName /tdn:$targetDatabaseName /TargetServerName:$databaseServerName /p:GenerateSmartDefaults=true

    Write-host "Finished"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The msdn documentation is a little light in this area but the deploy methods are asynchronous so the method completes but the operation is still on-going.

You need to hook up the "DacServices.ProgressChanged" event and look at the status on the event arg passed in - but note that I am pretty certain you get a few "Complete" messages for each stage so you will need to also see what the message says when it finishes and also if it failed with an error.

ed